# How to create database changes if enable migrations was not turned on

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using Entity Framework and MVC5 with Code First Methodology.  I also use branching in TFS to work on different modules without impacting a release.  I forgot to enable migrations in one of my branches and wanted to see if anyone had a solution to create the database changes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should post what you tried here, otherwise we cannot help you. First google, then ask. Thanks!

Comment: I was thinking about updating the configuration.cs file under the Migrations folder with a copy from the branch.  Not sure what if that is best practice.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps I performed to make this work (after merging all the branches):

1. Enable-migration -force (in the main branch - I had to use -force because one of the branches had enabled migrations already).
2. Next I ran update-database, however this failed because the migration file from the sub-branch was setup to create all the tables, instead of just the changes.  I deleted the create table code for all tables, and kept the create table for the new table and run update-database again.
3. Finally to get the changes from the second sub-branch, I ran the add-migration command, followed by the udpate-database command.